# Laravel 5 handling one to one relationships

Tags: laravel-5

I am trying to understand something.  I have a projects table which has certain fields.  I then have a document table which has a foreign key to a project.  To demonstrate, I have the following schemas

```
Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('contactName')->default('');
    $table->string('projectName')->default('');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('document', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->longText('documentType')->default('');
    $table->longText('documentContent')->default('');
    $table->integer('projectId')->unsigned()->default(0);
    $table->foreign('projectId')->references('id')->on('projects')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

My projects Model then has the following

```
public function document()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Document', 'projectId');
}
```

And my document model has the following

```
public function project()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Project', 'projectId');
}
```

So a project can have one document.  Here is what I am trying to understand.  My document is created after the project.  So first, I create a project by filling in the form linked to the projects create function.  On completion of this, I am then taken to that projects show page.  On the show page, I have a form to complete the document

```
{!! Form::model(new App\Document, 
    [
        'class'=>'form-horizontal',
        'route' => ['document.store', $project->id]
    ]) 
!!}

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('documentType', 'Document Type:', array('class' => 'col-sm-5 control-label blue')) !!}
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        {!! Form::textArea('documentType', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('documentContent', 'Document Data:', array('class' => 'col-sm-5 control-label blue')) !!}
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        {!! Form::textArea('documentContent', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::submit('Save Data', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
</div>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

So that calls the documents store function to save the data to the database.

This all works fine, data is saved as well as the projectId so I am able to link a document to a project.  However, if I now visit the show page for that project again, I have an empty form.  If I fill in this form, it saves a second row to the database which has the same projectId as the first.

Does this not contradict the one to one relationship if it allows me to create two documents for a project?  How am I able to make sure only one document is saved, and next time I visit the show page for a project it might instead have a button to show the document.

Thanks

Comment: why cant u save projectId in session and use it when you are making the view?

Comment: The document may not be made immediately, unless I am missing the point here?

Comment: Thats exaclty the point. store the projectId in session and use it for making document. when u did it , store the documentId in the session and then use it for the view. plz tell me if u need example

Comment: Thanks, I think I may need a little example.  I am just trying to understand how the view can only be used once, so it sticks to the one to one relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose u do these in order to make the project:

```
$project = new Project();
$project->contactName = 'something';
$project->projectName = 'somethingElse';
$project->save(); //So you will have the id now!

return redirect()->intended('showPage')->with('project_id'  , $project->id);
```

So you are redirected to showPage and the projectId is stored in the sessions. Now in the showPage you have another form to make a document. but first retrieve the project U have just created like this:

```
if(session()->has('project_id')){
    $pId = session('project_id');
    $project = Project::find($pId);
}
```

now easily use the project for as many document u want!
Next we suppose that u registered the document and put the documntId in the session too.

```
Session::put('documentId' , $document->id);
```

so in the top of showPage just add some checks:

```
$result = DB::table('document')
          ->where(['id'=>Session::get('documentId') , 'projectId'=>$project->id])->get();
if($result != null){
// so just show the information not the submit form!
}
else{
 //show the form to submit the document!
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the information, helps a lot.  One question - as far as I know, a session will last while the app is open.  What happens if I create the document for a Project, and then close the app?  Next time I visit the show page, because there is no document session, it will show the create form again?

Comment: so glad to help u! Just like I said in the last part of the answer, in order to find out whether there are any documents related to the project or not , you can simply get a query from DB to find. another approach is fixing the sessions like this : One workaround is to check your php.ini file. You may have this variable defined: session.gc_maxlifetime. By default it is set to 1440. Just comment or delete it.
From this time on you session may work properly using your session.php config values.